# How to fix a Windows partition after removing Bootcamp?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition, dual-boot

I have a 2009 MBP. For a long time I've had a Bootcamp partition on the hard drive, recently I bought a second SSD and installed it in the Optibay and installed Windows on it. As it was going well I thought I'd give OSX the full hard drive so I used Bootcamp Assistant to remove the Bootcamp partition on drive #1. Drive #2 still has the Windows 7 so I restarted expecting REfit to pick up the changes and assumed I would be working as normal. However when I try to start Windows I get a black screen and the words:

```
Bootmgr is missing.
Press Ctrl + Alt + Del to restart.
```

Furthermore REfit is still showing the old partition-based Windows install as a boot option but I know its not there.

Is there a way of fixing all this without wiping, repartitioning and reinstalling Windows using Bootcamp?

Comment: Did you select (in boot camp) "restore" "restore to single partition"?

Comment: I recall reading something about deleting the drivers on the second hard drive (windows). Removing Windows partition with boot camp, then adding the windows drivers after..